# Google Now integration with third party application

Tags: android, google-now

Like google now, i want to show notification in my application like
"Your movie starts in 1 hr, start now"
"Traffic update"
"Weather Update"

Is there a way to integrate with the Google Now?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (Lollipop), no.

You can implement your own events into Google Now.

In Android M, there will be such a thing as "[Now on Tap](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDevelopers/posts/SCM2tT1gXat)". This will overlay Google Now on your App, its feature set is quite secretive though currently.